# Operand type clash: int is incompatible with uniqueidentifier. How to make the uniqueidentifier an OUTPUT

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to have this procedure to work properly by being able to get the output of the `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` value, but when I try to execute the query it gives me the error

> Operand type clash: int is incompatible with uniqueidentifier

I have tried different things but can't come to a solution.

here is my code

```
-- =================================================
-- Example: [mob].[procedureName] 369, NULL, 23741, "somePath", "SomeName", "clientName", NULL
-- Example: [mob].[procedureName] 
-- Example: [mob].[procedureName] 
-- =================================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [mob].[uspInsertEmail]      
(
@ParamCompany VARCHAR(50),
@ParamDate DATETIME,
@ParamCreatedBy VARCHAR(50),
@ParamFilePath VARCHAR(200),
@ParamFileName VARCHAR(100),
@ParamClientFileName VARCHAR(100),
@ParamGUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER OUTPUT
)
AS
DECLARE @GUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER=NEWID() 

INSERT INTO [mob].[tblEmail]
(           
[Company],
[GuidString],
[Date],
[CreatedBy]
) 
VALUES  
(           
@ParamCompany,
@GUID,
@ParamDate,
@ParamCreatedBy
)                               
INSERT INTO [mob].[tblEmailAttachment]
(           
[Email],
[FilePath],
[FileName],
[ClientFileName],
[CreatedBy]
) 
VALUES                  
(           
IDENT_CURRENT ('mob.tblEmail'),              
@ParamFilePath,
@ParamFileName,
@ParamClientFileName,
@ParamCreatedBy
)

SELECT @GUID AS EmailGuid
SET @ParamGUID = @GUID
```

I read that I would need to make the `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` to be in an `OUTPUT` clause, but don't exactly know how to make the `@GUID` as `OUTPUT`

Comment: The way you have it will return your guid variable. If you want it as an outbound parameter you need to define it in the list of parameters with the keyword OUTPUT.

Comment: BTW, I would recommend using SCOPE_IDENTITY() instead of IDENT_CURRENT in your second insert statement to avoid issues with concurrency.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but would that be even if I am not passing the value as a parameter? because it is declared and instantiated as a local variable.

Comment: If you want it as an output parameter it must be in the list of parameters. My guess is the error is because the guidstring column is not the uniqueidentifier datatype.

Comment: See this link for using output parameters. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378108%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

Comment: It actually is uniqueidentifier data type. I tried adding it to the parameter list but still get the error. Thanks for the link

Comment: Then you need to share the entire code not just portions of it. Update your question and include the whole procedure.

Comment: Ok I have edited it, are you able to identify the issue here? Thx

Answer (score 1):

I would make this a lot simpler. Something like this.

```
-- =================================================
-- Example: [mob].[procedureName] 369, NULL, 23741, "somePath", "SomeName", "clientName", NULL
-- Example: [mob].[procedureName] 
-- Example: [mob].[procedureName] 
-- =================================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [mob].[uspInsertEmail]      
(
    @ParamCompany VARCHAR(50),
    @ParamDate DATETIME,
    @ParamCreatedBy VARCHAR(50),
    @ParamFilePath VARCHAR(200),
    @ParamFileName VARCHAR(100),
    @ParamClientFileName VARCHAR(100),
    @ParamGUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER OUTPUT
)
AS
    set nocount on;

    select @ParamGUID = NEWID();

    INSERT INTO [mob].[tblEmail]
    (           
        [Company],
        [GuidString],
        [Date],
        [CreatedBy]
    ) 
    VALUES  
    (           
        @ParamCompany,
        @ParamGUID,
        @ParamDate,
        @ParamCreatedBy
    )                               

    INSERT INTO [mob].[tblEmailAttachment]
    (           
        [Email],
        [FilePath],
        [FileName],
        [ClientFileName],
        [CreatedBy]
    ) 
    VALUES                  
    (           
        SCOPE_IDENTITY(),              
        @ParamFilePath,
        @ParamFileName,
        @ParamClientFileName,
        @ParamCreatedBy
    )
```

Comment: it worked, thanks for the answers. It turned out that the procedure was correct, the issue was a misspelling on the procedure name that it was misleading the error to something else. Thanks +1 @Sean Lange

Comment: It my response worked for you, you should mark it as the answer.

Comment: I guess he got what he wanted and never came back to SO (or he is constantly rotating accounts). But here is an upvote ;)